# Proving that $a_j=a_{j-1}+a_{j-2}$ cannot converge to a finite limit.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

So I'm currently working on some exercises that I've been assigned in the "Sequences" chapter of my text (titled *Foundations of Analysis* by Steven G. Krantz) for my real analysis course.  There's only four questions, and so far I haven't had much success in my attempts to do them.  For example, the first question I've been assigned is:

"Let $a_1,a_2>0$ and for $j\geq3$ define $a_j=a_{j-1}+a_{j-2}$.  Show that this sequence cannot converge to a finite limit."

I want to say that I use the following definition from the text to go about proving this:

**Definition 2.3**:  "A sequence {$a_j$} of real numbers is said to *converge* to a real number $\alpha$ if, for each $\epsilon>0$, there is an integer $N>0$ such that if $j>N$ then |$a_j-\alpha$|$<\epsilon$.  We call $\alpha$ the *limit* of the sequence {$a_j$}."

Minus the fact that this definition does not make alot of sense to me, it seems that I should somehow use it to show that the sequence in question does not converge to a finite limit.  Some things I noticed (which could be entirely wrong) were:

1. {$a_j$} would diverge since it appears to tend to infinity.  However, my text does not discuss what one would do in such a case.
2. You can write any term of the sequence $a_i$ in terms of $a_1$ and $a_2$, although I am not sure if this can help me here.

Overall, I am just unsure as to how to begin this problem.  This particular section of the chapter focuses heavily on Cauchy sequences, so I was also thinking that maybe I should be turning my attention to that particular definition and see what I can come up with.  At this point, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: This exercise really is to get you to understand the definition.  Note $a_n > n*a_1$  try to show rhe defining is impossible.

Comment: The solution is given by $A\mu_{-}^{n} + B\mu_{+}^{n}$ where $\mu_{\pm}$ satisfy $\mu^{2} - \mu - 1 = 0$. Check the limit $n \to \infty$ for given values of $a_{0}$ and $a_{1}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the limit exists as a finite number, say $L$, then you can apply limit law to the relation $a_j=a_{j-1}+a_{j-2}$ to get 
$$L=L+L.$$
Thus $L=0$. Thus you only have to show the limit cannot be 0.

Answer (score 1):

A convergent sequence is necessarily bounded: take $\varepsilon=1$ in your definition, then there exists an $N$ such that $|a_j-\alpha|<1$ for all $j\ge N$. Therefore:

$$|a_j|\le |a_j-\alpha|+|\alpha|<1+|\alpha|\quad \forall j\ge N$$

It therefore suffices to see that the sequence is unbounded.

Comment: Two questions to this:  first, why $\epsilon=1$?  Can it be any number?  Second, how did you form the main inequality you used in your answer?

Comment: @ThyArtisMath The definition says that for any positive number $\varepsilon$, there exists an $N$ (depending on $\varepsilon$) such that etc. I can take any $\varepsilon>0$, I took $\varepsilon=1$ for convenience. Regarding your second question, recall that $|x+y|\le |x|+|y|$ for any $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, so:
$|a_j|=|(a_j-\alpha)+\alpha|\le|a_j-\alpha|+|\alpha|$.

Answer (score 1):

Your first observation is sufficient, with a little work. Let $b=\min\{a_1,a_2\}$, and prove by induction on $n$ that $a_n\ge nb$ for all $n\in\Bbb Z^+$.

Now suppose that the sequence converged to some $\alpha\in\Bbb R$. Then no matter how small you chose $\epsilon>0$, some whole tail of the sequence would lie entirely inside the open interval $(\alpha-\epsilon,\alpha+\epsilon)$. That is, there would be an $N\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $a_n\in(\alpha-\epsilon,\alpha+\epsilon)$ for every $n>N$. (Recall that $|x-\alpha|<\epsilon$ means precisely that $\alpha-\epsilon<x<\alpha+\epsilon$.) In particular, we can take $\epsilon=1$ and conclude that a whole tail of the sequence lies entirely within the interval $(\alpha-1,\alpha+1)$. Is that compatible with the observation in the first paragraph?

Comment: May I ask what you mean by "some whole tail of the sequence"?  I think I understand what you're saying, minus that bit.

Comment: @ThyArtisMath: By a *tail* of the sequence I mean all of the terms from any given point on. The subsequence of terms $a_n$ with $n\ge 100$ is a tail of the sequence; so is the subsequence of terms $a_n$ with $n\ge 5$. Here specifically we’re looking at the tail consisting of all terms $a_n$ with $n>N$. (And I had a typo with $m$ for $N$ that probably didn’t help; by the time you see this I’ll have fixed it.)

Answer (score 1):

I was trying this problem and was hoping for some feedback as I am not sure if I proved it or not...

For $\epsilon>0,\exists N:|a_j-a_{j+1}|<\epsilon$ for$j>N$.

$a_j=a_{j-1}+a_{j-2}$

$|a_j|=|a_{N+1}+a_{j-1}+a_{j-2}-a_{N+1}|$    I added zero in a unique way.

$|a_j|\leq|a_{N+1}|+|a_{j-1}+a_{j-2}-a_{N+1}|$  Triangle inequality

$|a_j|\leq|a_{N+1}|+|a_j-a_{N+1}|$  Substitute in $a_j$

```
for j>N, |a_j-a_{N+1}| < epsilon
```

$|a_j|\leq|a_{N+1}|+\epsilon$

$|a_j|-|a_{N+1}|\leq\epsilon$ Since epsilon can't be negative and we know $|a_j|-|a_{N+1}|<0$, is there a contradiction?